# Launch app in android 10 from another app

Tags: android

I have below sample code to launch another app from my application

```
Context ctx = MainService.getContextOfApplication();
Intent intent = ctx.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
ctx.startActivity(intent);
```

This code work in android 8.1 and lower, but don't work on android 9 and upper. Code run without any exception or error, but nothing happens in phone.
Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you tell us which app you are trying to launch, better tell package name, because this method works fine for me.

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal For example: Messaging app by package name "com.android.messaging". Please be careful that code must work in android 10

Comment: I think this is due to different package name, For my Test Device (Xiaomi Redmi 6) with android 9, it's com.android.mms